# Is this Applied Mathematics?

Tags: education

I wanted to learn **Applied mathematics**, mostly due to it being similar to or having relation to Object Orientated Programming (**OOP**), and thought it would help alot.

I searched all over the internet. (at least 1-2 hours of searching), couldn't find anything "*free*". I wouldn't mind buying a book, but if there's a free PDF, or video I wouldn't like to pay.

I found this one series on youtube that teaching "applied mathematics". 
featuring topics like "*set theory*", "*functions*", and "*algebraic structures*".

So far, I'm almost done with set Theory. But what I noticed is that there's a lot of dislikes on the video and people tend not to like it. (around 30% dislikes)

As a student/person learning Applied Mathematics, I have no idea if it's right or wrong. I just learn regardless.

The youtube series is: [First Lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NcsjSnyxWfU).

Has anyone watched it?, if so is it good? There aren't many "free" ways to learn it, so I just took what I could get.

Not In college, to young. As most people referred me to learning it in college. I've been learning "Set Theory" pretty easily. Mainly due to know some **OOP**.

And also last question. Is it a smart thing to do?, by that I mean learning Applied Mathematics in High school.

---

Also new here to "stackexchange", so if this is the wrong page or section to post this question in, please refer me to the correct page.

Answer (score 0):

OOP is a paradigm to organize code and data. This can be used e.g. to model physical and geometric problems.

The large arsenal of applied mathematics is also used for modeling and solving such problems. That is about the commonality with OOP I can see.

There is a relationship between the theories of computation and constructive mathematics, e.g. [this author](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/cs257/archive/per-martin-lof/constructive-math.pdf) ends with

> In fact, I do not think that the search for logically ever more satisfactory high level programming languages can stop short of anything but a language in which (constructive) mathematics can be adequately expressed.

And indeed this search produced other programming paradigms like functional programming or declarative programming which are using and supporting mathematical concepts.

Back to learning applied mathematics: Learning (university) mathematics usually starts with some set theory, but mostly linear algebra and calculus. From this differential equations, numerical analysis, applied algebra, functional analysis, probability theory and statistics, discrete mathematics etc build up.

If a linear algebra or calculus course is too abstract a course for engineering mathematics might be an alternative.